# why prototype allow multiple instances share variables?

Tags: javascript

Say,

```
function Person(name) {
    this.name = name;
}

Person.prototype.share = [];

Person.prototype.printName = function() {
    alert(this.name);
}

var person1 = new Person('Byron');
var person2 = new Person('Frank');

person1.share.push(1);
person2.share.push(2);
console.log(person2.share); //[1,2]
```

In the above, share can be used by all instances. I am wondering if this is specific to Javascript? anything similar for other OOP language like C++, C# or Java?

Comment: Do you know if those languages have prototypal inheritance?

Comment: These are Javascript's nearest equivalent of class variables.

Comment: This implementation is specific t Javascript, but most other languages have something similar, they are usually called `static` class variables but sometimes have other names like `shared`

Comment: static variables in JS live under a constructor, not under an instance. for example, Object.keys() and Date.parse().

Comment: for other language, instance cannot access static variable; so it is quite different from Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Because that's how prototypes work.

In classical OOP (Java, C# etc.), classes are just "templates", and inheritance is just combining the "templates" for instances to be created from. In prototypal inheritance, an instance is an object whose parent *is a live object*. They don't just share definition, they share the same live instance of a parent.

So why does it work? That's because of how prototype lookups work. If some property isn't found in the instance, the engine looks for it in the parent. If still not there, it looks higher up in the prototype chain until it reaches the root object. If still not there, the engine can declare it `undefined` (if it's a property lookup) or throw an error (if you called a method).

```
instance -> parent -> parent -> parent -> Object
```

That's how JS "inherits". It basically just looks for the ancestor that has that something you want, and operate at that level. This is why instances of `Person` can push to `share`, because they have a common parent object.

```
person1
        \
         > Person.prototype (which has share[])
        /
person2
```

In order to prevent such sharing, one can override it by declaring a `share` property in the constructor (which when instantiated, creates one per instance). Another is just putting a `share` property on the instance. Descendant properties take precedence over ancestor properties, since lookup starts from the bottom.

```
function Person(name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.share = []; // Instances will have share, but not shared anymore
}

// or 
person1.share = []; // Creates a share for person1 only
```

Comment: As a result, OP's example works only because `share` points to an object (Array) which content is modified by its member functions. If one changes the `share = ''` and modifies using `+=` the behavior will change because on assignment the object instance will get it's own member `share` and prototype look-up won't be performed on next access (i.e. `console.log(person2.share)`)